# Is a correct way only copying files to take a mysql backup?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to take a backup from my Mysql Server.

Is it a correct way to shut down the Mysql and copy all files from the directory"/var/lib/mysql" and paste them on another directory?

Comment: *Is it a correct way* No, this may result in both lost/damaged data and non-startable MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible to clone a machine to make another working machine, what you describe is likely to work.  However, two things are missing:  The mysql code and the configuration file.  The config may need to be edited for then machine.

There are several other ways to take a backup:

- mysqldump (and variants: xtrabackup, mariadbaackup, etc)
- lvm snapshot